# How to modify value from a form request before it is submitted in the DB?

Tags: forms, symfony, events

I use an eventlisterner to check some values returned by the user/author before actually submitting them to the DB.

My form allow ROLE_USERS to change some attribut (like statut) to the Entity Article. Article has attribute such as statut(Published, Delete) and tobecheked('author wants to delete this article', 'null') which allow ROLE_ADMIN to review easily some article.

Anyway. I want that when Author submit **statut**=>'DELETE' the value of statut **tobechecked** to be turned into => 'author wants to delete this article'.

Here what I tried but this is not working.

```
class Article extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('Statut', ...);
            ->add('toBeChecked',  ...);

    $dynamicSubmissionFunc = function (FormEvent $event)
    {
       $data = $event->getData();
       if($data['statut'] == 'DELETE')
       {
           // HOW CAN I MODIFY HERE THE VALUE OF ARTICLE ATTRIBUTE
           $data['toBeChecked'] = 'author wants to delete this article';
           // nothing is changed in the attribute toBeChecked.
       }
    }
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $dynamicSubmissionFunc);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I figured out. You need to set your data back to the event:

```
$event->setData($data);
```

Comment: Sorry. I did a mistake. Now I edited my answer. You need to check it.

Comment: Great It works, at least for data in the form. But what if I also want to modify an attribute which is not submited in the form? is this possible to change it? (I mean let's imagine that the attribute 'tobeChecked' was not added to the fields, then how could I change its value in the DB regarding submitted value of user.

Comment: You should use Doctrine event listeners or lifecycle callbacks instead. It will be independent of your forms and will be executed every time when you update your entity (from form, directly from controller and even if it is modified by another bundle)

Comment: but I need to modify 'tobeChecked' depending on value submitted by the user for the 'statut' attribut. And actually only if user = ROLE_AUTHOR, not if user = ROLE_ADMIN. **Do you think it is possible with Doctrine event listeners and lifecycle callbacks?**

Comment: It is possible with event listeners but with lifecycle callbacks you will have access to only your entity.